# decrease blank space in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I m having a php form from where the output is converted into tcpdf. If some data are not entered in some rows those rows should not reflect in pdf or blank space should not appear in pdf. How can we avoid blank space in tcpdf.If 1st row is entered in php and 2nd row is not entered. Space should appear between other details.Can we use script in tcpdf? How to hide the space 
[image]

It appears this way in pdf
I dont want space to appear between projects and collaborations

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$html = '

        <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ';
$html .= '</h3>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="99%">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4"   color="#000" align="left" ><b>PROJECTS</b></td>
                                    </tr>




                                        <tr>
                                <td width="7%">Sl.No</td>
                                        <td width="28%">Project Title</td>
                                        <td width="19%">Funding agency</td>
                                        <td width="18%">Broad area of investigation</td>
                                        <td width="14%">Duration</td>
                                        <td width="14%">Amount sanctioned</td>

                                            <td width="0.2%">';



    $html .= '</td></tr>
<tr>

                             <td width="7%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($slno);
    $html .= '</td>         


                                 <td width="28%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($project1);
    $html .= '</td>
                                  <td width="19%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($funding1);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="18%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($bai1);
    $html .= '</td>
          <td width="14%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($duration1);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="14%">';

    $html .= $amount1;
    $html .= '</td>

                                   </tr>                                   
                                <tr>


 <td width="7%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($slno1);
    $html .= '</td>         

                                 <td width="28%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($project2);
    $html .= '</td>
                                  <td width="19%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($funding2);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="18%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($bai2);
    $html .= '</td>
          <td width="14%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($duration2);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="15%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($amount2);
    $html .= '</td>

                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>


 <td width="7%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($slno2);
    $html .= '</td> 

                                 <td width="28%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($project3);
    $html .= '</td>
                                  <td width="19%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($funding3);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="18%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($bai3);
    $html .= '</td>
          <td width="14%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($duration3);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="15%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($amount3);
    $html .= '</td>

                                   </tr>

            <tr>


 <td width="7%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($slno3);
    $html .= '</td>         

                                 <td width="28%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($project4);
    $html .= '</td>
                                  <td width="19%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($funding4);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="18%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($bai4);
    $html .= '</td>
          <td width="14%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($duration4);
    $html .= '</td>
                                   <td width="15%">';

    $html .= stripslashes($amount4);
    $html .= '</td>

                                   </tr>                       

            </table>

            <br/><br/>
```

Comment: put condition `if($slno!='')` to create `<tr>`